# undefined is not a function (near '...React.createClass...')

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to get this library working: https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-form-native

However when I run it on my local machine I get the error: `undefined is not a function (near '...React.createClass...')`

The only hint that I could find is here: https://github.com/jayesbe/react-native-cacheable-image/issues/60 where someone stated that React 16 removed createClass.

When I follow the steps here https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html#migrating-from-reactcreateclass

I get an error involving promises. I'm not too clear how to use this library and would appreciate some guidance.

edit: the example code:

```
// index.ios.js

'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var t = require('tcomb-form-native');
var { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableHighlight } = React;

var Form = t.form.Form;

// here we are: define your domain model
var Person = t.struct({
  name: t.String,              // a required string
  surname: t.maybe(t.String),  // an optional string
  age: t.Number,               // a required number
  rememberMe: t.Boolean        // a boolean
});

var options = {}; // optional rendering options (see documentation)

var AwesomeProject = React.createClass({

  onPress: function () {
    // call getValue() to get the values of the form
    var value = this.refs.form.getValue();
    if (value) { // if validation fails, value will be null
      console.log(value); // value here is an instance of Person
    }
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {/* display */}
        <Form
          ref="form"
          type={Person}
          options={options}
        />
        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={this.onPress} underlayColor='#99d9f4'>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Save</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: 50,
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: 'white',
    alignSelf: 'center'
  },
  button: {
    height: 36,
    backgroundColor: '#48BBEC',
    borderColor: '#48BBEC',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 8,
    marginBottom: 10,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
});
```

Comment: are you calling `React.createClass` in your code?

Comment: @azium yes, I've added the example code in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you try this instead?

(PS this is so old school... I probably suggest not using this library at all)

```
import React from 'react'
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native'
import t from 'tcomb-form-native'

var Form = t.form.Form

// here we are: define your domain model
var Person = t.struct({
  name: t.String,              // a required string
  surname: t.maybe(t.String),  // an optional string
  age: t.Number,               // a required number
  rememberMe: t.Boolean        // a boolean
})

var options = {} // optional rendering options (see documentation)

class AwesomeProject extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.onPress = this.onPress.bind(this)
  }

  onPress() {
    // call getValue() to get the values of the form
    var value = this.refs.form.getValue()
    if (value) { // if validation fails, value will be null
      console.log(value) // value here is an instance of Person
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {/* display */}
        <Form
          ref="form"
          type={Person}
          options={options}
        />
        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={this.onPress} underlayColor='#99d9f4'>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Save</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: 50,
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: 'white',
    alignSelf: 'center'
  },
  button: {
    height: 36,
    backgroundColor: '#48BBEC',
    borderColor: '#48BBEC',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 8,
    marginBottom: 10,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
})

export default AwesomeProject
```

Comment: `Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) ... but got an object. Likely forgot to export your component` but when I add export default AwesomeProject. I get `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.bind.onPress')`

Comment: this.onPress = this.bind.onPress(this) should be
this.onPress = this.onPress.bind(this) @azium

Comment: add this line `export default AwesomeProject;` and the code works :p